# Saving a collection of SerializableAttributes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have several `Employee` objects which are all `SerializableAttribute`s. This is due to WCF, because these are objects passed between the client and the server.

I would now like to save and load several of these, either to a file or by using `System.Properties` namespace. With the System properties, I could not find a way to save them because the types that are allowed are pretty limited: int, string, float and some others. There's nothing involving serializable, and the only collection available is a string collection.

What would be the best approach? I'm not sure what is the proper way to save a collection, like List<> of SerializableAttributes to a file.  Otherwise, I can use System.properties and I could do it the "hard way" by converting the objects to strings and back, but this approach will be pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many alternatives such as: `JavaScriptSerializer  XmlSerializer DataContractSerializer DataContractJsonSerializer  BinaryFormatter SoapFormatter`.

(BTW: `Serializable` attribute is only used by BinaryFormatter and no need for WCF)